# ruby rename elements of array with elements of different array

Tags: ruby, arrays, mapping

i have a file that looks like this:

```
TTITLE0=track name 1
TTITLE1=track name 2
```

and a directory that contains `track01.cdda.wav.mp3` and `track02.cdda.wav.mp3`

i have the following code, which creates 2 different arrays, 1 with the track names and 1 with the track titles:

```
tracks = Dir.glob("*.mp3")

tracknames = Array.new
File.open('read').each do |line|
  if line =~ /TTITLE/
    tracknames << line.split("=")[1].strip!
  end
end
```

this gives me 2 arrays:

```
["track name 1", "track name 2"]
```

and

```
["track01.cdda.wav.mp3", "track02.cdda.wav.mp3"]
```

i would like to rename the files in the second array with the elements of the first array. so, `"track01.cdda.wav.mp3"` would become `"track name 1.mp3"`.

here is what i have tried so far:

```
tracks.map {|track| File.rename("#{tracks}", "#{tracknames}.mp3") }
```

and i get the error:

```
No such file or directory - track01.cdda.wav.mp3track02.cdda.wav.mp3 or track name 1track name 2 (Errno::ENOENT)
```

i have to keep in mind that in the future there could be any number of elements in each array, but the numbers will be equal to each other.

any ideas?

Comment: anyone like to explain why this got downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260):

```
tracks.zip(tracknames).each do |track, trackname|
  File.rename track, "#{trackname}.mp3"
end
```

Alternatively (less fun, but doesn't create an intermediary array of arrays prior to enumeration):

```
tracks.each_with_index do |track, i|
  File.rename track, "#{tracknames[i]}.mp3"
end
```

Comment: awesome, 1st one worked for me no issue. what if i wanted to add a number to the beginning of the track number? could i use the second example and File.rename track, "#[i] #{tracknames[i]}.mp3"?

Comment: You could use the second technique like that, yes, or you could: `tracks.zip(tracknames).each_with_index{ |(track, trackname), i| ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to have two arrays? You could get by with just one:

```
tracks = Dir.glob("*.mp3")
File.open('read').each do |line|
  if line =~ /TTITLE/
    to = line.split("=")[1].strip!
    File.rename tracks.shift, "#{to}.mp3"
  end
end
```

And then end of that, your [`shift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000228) calls will have left `tracks` empty but that may not be a problem.

As far as your:

```
tracks.map {|track| File.rename("#{tracks}", "#{tracknames}.mp3") }
```

approach goes, the problem is that you're calling `to_s` on the `tracks` array when you interpolate it as `"#{tracks}"` and that just mashes all the individual strings in `tracks` together as one big pile of "not what you want". Similarly for `tracknames`. And [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) isn't what you want as you're not doing anything with the `File.rename` return values. However, you could do this:

```
tracks.each {|track| File.rename("#{track}", "#{tracknames.shift}.mp3") }
```

Or use [`each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001511):

```
tracks.each_with_index {|track,i| File.rename("#{track}", "#{tracknames[i]}.mp3") }
```

That one would leave `tracknames` intact.

Comment: i had thought about that, but couldn't get it to work. this just takes care of the renaming as soon as it finds an eligible line to rename it with. cool.

Comment: @rick: That's called "true laziness" which, unlike "false laziness", is a good thing. Except when it isn't.